# Why can't two Silicon tetraoxide tetrahedrons share an edge or a face?

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry, glass

Our teacher told us about structural types of silicate minerals (neosilicate, sorosilicate, cyclosilicates ...) saying that those tetrahedrons can only share one corner (oxygen), but he didn't give us any explanation, could anyone help me with this?

Comment: That would be too much of angular strain.

Comment: What if the angles facing each other, symmetrical in respect to the potential shared edge,  were equal?

Comment: They **are** equal; so what?

Comment: In that case, both angles would be 109°, which does not qualify as "abnormal" for a tetrahedron, i don't see source of the strain here.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about the $\ce{O-Si-O}$ angles. OK, but what about $\ce{Si-O-Si}$?

Comment: I found in the following page that the optimal angle for a bridging oxygen is 140°, and that it can vary from 120 to 180, when i visualize the two tetrahedrons, i would say that the angle must too sharp in the case of an edge or face sharing, causing the said strain, i'm i right?

Comment: Here is the link : https://books.google.dz/books?id=yMGzmOqYescC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=bridging+angle+si-o-si+angle&source=bl&ots=whvDBEnuMt&sig=SWFRYFEV8MZ11G4dVWLRyhCw6QU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA9anSm6DLAhVDqQ4KHfGlBD8Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=bridging%20angle%20si-o-si%20angle&f=false

Comment: That's right. If you have a 4-membered cycle, some of the angles must be too sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solid-state chemistry, we know a certain set of rules called the Pauling rules. One of them states that sharing faces or edges is unfavorable. Imagine your silicate-tetrahedra to share faces. That would equal the closest distance between two highly charged silicon cations. They both have a charge of +4, so there is really some repulsion. Same goes for the edges which is also quite close.

If you increase the overall size of the tetrahedron however by exchanging oxide by sulfide you will end up in the silicon(IV)sulfide structure which is essentially long chains of tetrahedra that share edges. Here by introducing a much larger anion the distance between the two silicon centers is increased and edges can be shared.